# Поиск минимума в очереди C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, очередь, struct

Реализую поиск минимума в очереди, но столкнулся с проблемой, что на больших массивах слишком долго работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли ускорить?

```
struct Node {
    int data = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};

struct Queue {
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;
    int q_size = 0;

    bool is_empty() {
        return this->head == nullptr;
    }
    int min() {
        int min;
        Node* temp = this->head;
        min = temp->data;
        int help = this->q_size;
        while (help) {
            if (temp->data < min)
                min = temp->data;
            temp = temp->next;
            --help;
        }
        return min;
    }
};
```

Comment: Задача какая - очередь по приоритетам или простая очередь по порядку добавления с дополнительной функцией текущего минимума?

Comment: Простая очередь по порядку добавления с дополнительной функцией минимума

Comment: Ну, храните значение минимума при очереди, а добавляя новый элемент в очередь, обновляйте его. Тогда это - поиск минимума - будет очень быстрым :)

Comment: @Harry Ну-ну ;) Голосом Куравлёва: А Козлевичу? Т.е. при извлечении что делать?

Comment: @Harry Элементы в очередь можно добавлять и убирать. Если убрать элемент из очереди, который был минимумом, ответ будет неправильный. Да и вообще хотелось бы в функцию оформить, если можно ускорить...

Comment: @MBo Ну, если извлекается минимальный - пересчитать :)

Comment: @MBo так если постоянно пересчитывать, будет еще медленнее, чем у меня написано

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте стек, хранящий пары элемент/минимум от дна до данного элемента

```
add(value) {
   curmin = min(curmin, value)
   stack.push(pair(value, curmin))
}

stackmin() {
   return stack.top().second
}
```

А теперь возьмите два таких стека и на их основе сделайте очередь:

```
queuemin() 
    return min(instack.stackmin(), outstack.stackmin())

add(value) {
   instack.add(value)  //min при этом обновляется
}

pop() {  
   if outstack пустой
      перекинуть в него всё из instack c помощью add (которая обновляет min)
   return outstack.pop()
}
```

Вот нашёл, где я это видел: [Модификация стека и очереди для нахождения минимума за O (1)](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/stacks_for_minima)